# How to read/write random chunks from large binary files properly?

Tags: c#, io, binaryfiles

I am writing a lib for working with binary files. Specifically "The Log Information Standard (LIS) 79 Subset", which has various types of records with entries of various datatypes. Each entry may be a single value, array or have more complex structure. File size may vary from 3-5 KBs to several GBs.

**Goal:** read and modify any part of the file of any size.

**What has been tried:**

- first implementation simply read the whole file, then wrote every record and datatype to appropriate class instance along with its buffer. It was perfectly fine for small files, but extremely slow and RAM hungry when file size is bigger than 1GB.
- then I tried to stop using buffers completely. Read the file, stored offset, size and type for each component. This approach worked well for reading, but as I understood after some research there are no way to insert data in the random position of the file.

So the question is how to properly handle such data without overusing RAM?

Comment: If you insist, though, have a look at [memory mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files).

Comment: Best way is to read one field at a time.  Binary data the field sizes are not consistent so you have to read like you second approach.  When writing the only guarantee method is to parse entire data and then write.  Reading the ZIP specification will give other solutions.  A zip file has directories and you can add files to the structure without reading everything.  But ZIP is a special type of binary file.

Comment: Wait, so this is actually about a specific File Type? Then of course, you must implement that File Type's specification. Which means, DB is out the window. That information would have been really helpful in the question.

Comment: To insert data into a binary file, you can use two files. Copy all the data up to the insertion point from the source to the destination file. Then write the data to be inserted to the destination file. Then write the remainder of the source file to the destination file. Then delete the source file and rename the destination file to the source file name.

Comment: Note that in this approach it's important that the temporary destination file should be on the same volume as the original file, otherwise renaming it at the end of the process will in fact copy all the data again.

Comment: Are you talking about this : https://dlisio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lis/specification.html ? Does Does ? _"The Log Information Standard (LIS) 1 is a binary file format for well logs, developed by Schlumberger in 1974. The 1974 version is commonly referred to as LIS79 or the 79 Subset."_

Comment: Yes, the that's the format.

Comment: Please feel free to use that link and [edit] your question to mention the **intention to implement that specific specification**. I'll delete my comments about using a DB instead.

Comment: Matthew Watson. It should work, but can be slow. That's the library, so I do not know how exactly it will be used and how many modifications will be done for a single file. In the worst (most likely unrealistic) case, when the are modifications in every entry I would have to store all changes in buffer (basicaly whole file), make another temp file with changes+offsets+sizes or rewrite the whole file after every change (which would  be noticeable on large files).

Comment: The thing is: It's an ancient binary log file format, designed for tape (!!). Which makes it _highly_ probable that the specification will _not_ favor random access (for write operations) but append-only access. But I am not at all familiar with it. What I am intending to say is: you _really_ need to deep-dive into the specs to find out what and how to implement.

Comment: As I understood from the specs, the format is not intended for editing. So I'm trying to figure it out how people normally deal with such large documents. Specification is already implemented, the problem is which tools or techniques would be appropriate to use in this case.

Comment: Just use a `FileStream` and seek to where you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no knowledge about LIS files, so this will will be about binary files in general.

Many binary file formats will have some type of index, as well as the actual data entries themselves. So reading the file would consist of scanning thru the index until you find what you are looking for and then jump to the offset specified in the index. The index might be defined in a chunk at the beginning of the file, or as a linked list, spread throughout the file. The actual format will likely be much more complicated, but it might be useful as a simplified mental model.

If you know the format you could simply use a [BinaryReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=net-7.0) to read values, and jump around in the file accordingly. Probably using some kind of state machine to keep track of what it is you are reading.

> insert data in the random position of the file

This is *really difficult* to do well. You will have to chose between wasting space, moving data around, and fragmentation. Databases spend a lot of effort at trying to find a happy medium between each extreme.

But if you are working with an existing format you will have the choice made for you. If the format is not designed for cheap insertions you will likely need to move the vast majority of data in the file, essentially require you to rewrite the entire thing. If you are lucky the format might allow appending of data cheaply.

If the format is not designed for cheap modification you should most likely need to convert it to some format that *is* cheap to modify. If you can keep it all in memory that will likely simplify things.

You could also just parse the index into an in memory structure, and keep any updates in memory until it is time to write data back to disk. So a imaginary format could look something like this. The key here is that you only read the least amount of data needed from disk, and that additions or modifications are done in memory. Note that this is only for illustrative purposes only.

```
public class Index
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IEntry> entries = new();

    public IEnumerable<string> List => entries.Keys;
    public byte[] Read(string key) => entries[key].Read();
    public void UpdateOrAdd(string key, byte[] data) => entries[key] = new MemoryEntry(data);

    public static Index Load(Stream source)
    {
        var br = new BinaryReader(source);
        var numEntries = br.ReadInt32();
        var result = new Index();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++)
        {
            var key = br.ReadString();
            var length = br.ReadInt32();

            // Note. Mixing index information and data like this will make it 
            // easy to read/append, but slower to load. 
            var offset = (int)br.BaseStream.Position;
            result.entries[key] = new FileEntry(source, offset, length);
            br.BaseStream.Position += length;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void Save(Stream destination)
    {
        var bw = new BinaryWriter(destination);
        bw.Write(entries.Count);
        var list = entries.ToList();
        foreach (var (key, value) in list)
        {
            bw.Write(key);
            bw.Write(value.Length);
            value.CopyTo(bw.BaseStream);
        }
    }
}

public interface IEntry
{
    public void CopyTo(Stream destination);
    public byte[] Read();
    public int Length { get; }
}

public class MemoryEntry : IEntry
{
    private readonly byte[] data;
    public MemoryEntry(byte[] data) => this.data = data;
    public void CopyTo(Stream destination) => destination.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    public byte[] Read() => data;
    public int Length => data.Length;
}

public class FileEntry : IEntry
{
    private readonly Stream fileStream;
    private readonly int offset;
    private readonly int length;

    public FileEntry(Stream fileStream, int offset, int length)
    {
        this.fileStream = fileStream;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public void CopyTo(Stream destination)
    {
        fileStream.Position = offset;
        fileStream.CopyTo(destination, length);
    }

    public byte[] Read()
    {
        fileStream.Position = offset;
        var result = new byte[length];
        fileStream.Position = offset;
        var bytesRead = fileStream.Read(result, 0, length);
        if (bytesRead != length) throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid binary format");
        return result;
    }

    public int Length => length;
}
```